# Accessing variables in an ESM that has been imported multiple times in a sequence

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

In ES module import, each module is loaded once in a sequence of imports.
Do the importing JS access the same variable in the imported class?
What would be the result of `console.log` in `bg.js`?

**mod.js**

```js
export class Mod {
  static value = 1;
}
```

**mod2.js**

```js
import {Mod} from './mod.js';

export class Mod2 {

  static {
    browser.tabs.onCreated.addListener(e => {
      Mod.value = 5;
    });
  }
}
```

**bg.js**

```js
import {Mod} from './mod.js';
import {Mod2} from './mod2.js';

// at later time
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener((...e) => {
  console.log(Mod.value);
});
```

Comment: It's the same variable, this is how imports work.